# Как вывести стикер "новинки" в Bitrix при определенном условии?

Tags: php, битрикс

Как в "Битрикс 1с управление сайтами 17.0" вывести значение "новинка" только в разделе "новинки" ?

Если сделать в общем компоненте catalog, то стикер появляется у всех.

Если сделать в компоненте "новинки", ничего не происходит.

*Делаю через добавления нового фильтра в компоненте:*

```
$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(array)
```

Как это делается? Через админку? Или можно прописать условие в общем каталоге наподобие этого:

```
<? if (раздел == новинки) {
     применить наклейку "новинки" 
   } 
?>
```

Пробовал узнать в каком разделе нахожусь - не получается. В Bitrix не очень шарю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем решил вопрос. Оказалась все просто. Объясняю для чайников в Bitrix.

1. Смотрим любой приближенный html элемент в нужном блоке. Как это делается:

   1.1 Открываем в браузере **"Просмотр кода"**, визуально выбираем нужный нам блок. Нажимаем на стрелочку **"Выбрать элемент"**

   1.2 Копируем название блока html.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Заходим в панель администрирования **Bitrix**

   2.1 Далее переходим в настройки `"Рабочий стол -> Контент -> Структура сайта -> Файлы и папки"` и нажимаем **CTRL+F**

   2.1.2 Далее в поле "Слово или фраза в файле" вписываем название элемента то что нашли ранее в блоке HTML.

   2.1.3 Далее ставим галочку "Во всех подпапках" и  Оставить "Искать в папке" - "/"

   2.1.4 В найденных файлах кроме "cache" методом тыка искать файл в котором проявятся изменения. Для пример можно вписывать в каждый файл надпись: `<? echo "Find page template!"; ?>`
3. Как только нашли нужный файл пишите в нем код:

```html
<? if($arResult['SECTION']['ID'] == ТУТ ID НУЖНОГО РАЗДЕЛА) { ?>
    <div class="i_item_stiker ipabs">
        <span class="i_item_stiker_NEW ifont85">НОВИНКА</span><br>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

*Тоже самое сделать для страницы каталог и для элемента/продукта*

**Результат:**

*В товаре раздела "Новинки" отображается вот так:*

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*В товаре прочих разделов отображается вот так:*

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*В каталоге отображается вот так:*

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]